# Magento 2: Get Product Attribute’s Select Option Id as Per Option Value For Configurable Product

Tags: product, magento-2.1, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I have fetched options attribute value as

```
<?php $packaging = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('packaging')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>
```

I am getting options value, I am trying to fetch option id as per value.
I tried but its not working

```
if ($packaging->usesSource()) {$option_id = $packaging->getSource()->getOptionId($packaging); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined **$attr** instead of **$packaging** in your code.

```
<?php 
    $packaging =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('packaging')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>  

    $attributeExist =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('packaging');

    if ($attributeExist->usesSource()) {
        echo $option_id = $attributeExist->getSource()->getOptionId($packaging); 
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: yes bro i have changed but its not working

Comment: Please check my updated code

Comment: what is my ;my custom label'

Comment: i will have to write my custom lavel in my code or anything else can you tell me

Comment: i tried once again its not working bro ...

Comment: Your attribute label like color attriubte with label is red then write red

Comment: attriubte option value i have fetched in variable <?php  $packaging =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('packaging')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>

Comment: please check  my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<?php foreach($product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $ak=>$av): ?>
            <?php if (strtolower($av['label']) == strtolower($product->getAttributeText('color'))):?>
            <p>id: <?= $av['value']?></p>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

For each product I am checking if it matches then I get the id of the product if there are not checks it will display all possible colours variation for that product it that is what you want.

Cheers